# ubuntu update-grub2 isn't recognising 3rd boot Sabayon

Tags: grub2, dual-boot

After installing Sabayon, Sabayon took over the boot process. I have reinstalled grub with

```
sudo grub-install /dev/sda
```

which I got from [ubuntu wiki grub2](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Installing)

Sabayon is an lvm on sda8 and sda9 see below.

```
sayth@sayth-TravelMate-5740G[~]
[22:03]:fdisj -l
zsh: correct 'fdisj' to 'fdisk' [nyae]? y

Disk /dev/sda: 500.1 GB, 500107862016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 60801 cylinders, total 976773168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x104abfd7

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *        2048    27265023    13631488   27  Hidden NTFS WinRE
/dev/sda2        27265024    27469823      102400    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda3        27469824   786911894   379721035+   7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda4       786913218   976768064    94927423+   5  Extended
/dev/sda5       786913280   812302335    12694528   83  Linux
/dev/sda6       812304384   816254975     1975296   82  Linux swap / Solaris
/dev/sda7       816257024   871153663    27448320   83  Linux
/dev/sda8       871155712   872179711      512000   83  Linux
/dev/sda9       872181760   976766975    52292608   8e  Linux LVM
```

However when you update-grub2 it doesn't detect that Sabayon exists, how can I fix this?

Edit I also then tried to redo it using grub-customizer but it just doesn't seem to detect it.

2nd Edit: I think from reading around it doesn't like /dev/sda8 as its a boot partition for the lvm on sda9. It flat out will not recognise it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mount the lvm partitions an run the grub update

The most succinct way to enable the volume groups is

```
sudo vgchange -a y
```

Simply run update grub to locate the lvms into grub.

```
sudo update-grub2
```

Comment: This answer would be much improved, if you edit it to include detailed information about *how* to do these things.

Comment: Actually this is correct. However as I intially feared that the lvm was causing the grub2 detection error I reinstalled to a standard instal and as such this resolved my issue similar to what you describe.                                              mount -t ext4 /dev/sda7 /mnt/
update-grub2

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 sudo update-grub2
```

This should update your grub2 cfg file.

Comment: that doesn't detect fedora , just win7 and Ubuntu .

Comment: Have you got the image in the /boot folder of grub?